# Understand a passage of example 1.24 of Hatcher book

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I try to understand what is going on in this example of Hatcher book

> Let us compute $\pi_1(R^3-K)$.[...] Namely, write $S^3-K$ as the union of $R^3-K$ and a open ball $B$ formed by compactification point together with the complement of a large closed ball in $R^3$ containing $K$. Both $B$ and $B\cap(R^3-K)$ are simply-connected, **the latter space being homeomorphic to $S^2\times R$**.

So, I see that, Hatcher abuse of notation here and keeping to he, all the notations as a personal secret. Let $\phi: S^3-\left\{N\right\} \to R^3$ be a stereographic projection, where $N =(0,0,0,1)$. I know that there is a continuous extension of $\phi$, namely $\tilde{\phi}$ such that $\tilde{\phi}(N) =\left\{\infty\right\}$. So $S^3$ is $R^3\cup \left\{\infty\right\}$ mod a homeomorphism.

Here, $U =\tilde{\phi}^{-1}(R^3-K)$ and $V =B$. I trying to do a precise description of $B$:
Let $\tilde{B}$ a large close ball in $R^3$ containing $K$. Take a complement of this ball, i.e, $R^3-\tilde{B}$. Define $B = \tilde{\phi}^{-1} (R^3-\tilde{B}\cup\left\{\infty\right\})$. (I think is that Hatcher is talking about ).

Therefore,
$$
U\cup V = \tilde{\phi}^{-1}(R^3-K) \cup \tilde{\phi}^{-1} ((R^3-\tilde{B})\cup\left\{\infty\right\}) =S^3-K.
$$

And,
$$
U\cap V = \tilde{\phi}^{-1} (R^3-\tilde{B})
$$

How to proof that the above intersection is homeomorphic to $S^2\times R$?

I begining to understand what is going on in $S^2$. If we pulled down a disk of $R^2$ the result in $S^2$ is a punched sphere, that is homeomorphic to a Disk, but I cannot find a analogy in $S^3$. There is a way to see this and construct a homeomorphism between them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$K$ and $B$ are disjoint, so $B \cap (\mathbb{R}^3 - K) = B \cap \mathbb{R}^3 = B - \{\infty\}$, which is just the complement of a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. By applying a suitable homeomorphism, we can take it to be $\mathbb{R}^3 - D^3$, where $D^3$ is the closed unit ball centered at the origin. From here it is easy to construct an explicit homeomorphism, e.g. take

\begin{align}
S^2 \times (1,\infty) &\to \mathbb{R}^3-D^3 \\
(\mathbf{x}, r) &\mapsto  r\mathbf{x}
\end{align}
composed with your favourite homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(1, \infty)$.

Note that an appropriate two-dimensional analogy is not removing a (closed) disk from $S^2$, but removing a disk *and a point* (since we first need to remove $\infty$ from $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$ to get $\mathbb{R}^2$), the result of which is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.